# Javascript .appendChild(tableA) move the table into a single cell.

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I have two tables in Javascript.

```
    <table  class="fHTML5" >

        <!-- TABLE HEADER-->
        <thead>
           <tr><td colspan=15>Mass Table - </td></tr>
            <tr id="RowHead">
                <th>ID</th><th>P Load (N)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="CTable" >

        </tbody>
     </table>

Example Output
===============
| ID | P Load |
---------------
|  1 |   700  |
|  2 |   800  |
---------------
```

And this table:

```
    <table  class="fHTML5" >

        <!-- TABLE HEADER-->
        <thead>
           <tr><td colspan=15>Mass Table - </td></tr>
            <tr id="RowHead">
                <th>ID</th><th>P Load (N)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="BTable" >

        </tbody>
     </table>

Example Output
===============
| ID | P Load |
---------------
|  1 |   100  |
|  2 |   500  |
---------------
```

I wish to copy of the body of the CTable into BTable, using this command.

```
this.BTable.appendChild(this.CTable);
```

However when I try this I get the following output:

```
Example Output
==========================
| ID            | P Load |
--------------------------
|  1            |   100  |
|  2            |   500  |
|  1  | 700     |
|  2  | 800     |
-----------------
```

instead of (this is what I'm looking for):

```
================
| ID  | P Load |
----------------
|  1  |   100  |
|  2  |   500  |
|  1  |   700  |
|  2  |   800  |
-----------------
```

Basically the appendChild command loads the entire table into the first cell. Is there a Javascript object/function that will append like minded tables together or do I have to manually code read the row and insert the row? Thanks

(Note: there are a few similar questions to this asked previously however none that I manage to get to work and only solutions found in JS )

Comment: `this.BTable.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", this.CTable)`

Answer (score 2):

You can try to insert all the rows from CTable to BTable.

```
var rows = this.CTable.querySelectorAll("tr");
for (var i = 0; i<rows.length; i++) {
    this.BTable.appendChild(rows[i]);
}
```

Comment: I see the only option for keeping the data in one Tbody is to copy the rows into the tBody. Thanks

Comment: @CromeX: Yes, although multiple `tbody`s behave like a single one. jcubic - Remember that the collection you get from `getElementsByTagName` is **live**. When you move row 0 into the other table, all the other rows in the collection move up because they're not in the source table anymore. So by looping as currently in the answer, you'll only move about half of the rows to the new table. Consider `this.CTable.querySelectorAll("tr")` since QSA returns a snapshot collection, or possibly even `document.querySelectorAll("#BTable > tr")` to avoid nested table issues.

Comment: ...or just loop until `rows.length` is `0` and append `rows[0]` each time.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking the browser to put a `tbody` element **inside** another `tbody` element. It can't do that, so it does its next best thing (which probably varies by browser).

If you want to put `CTable` *after* `BTable` (still in the same table, just moving the `tbody`), use [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore):

```
this.BTable.parentNode.insertBefore(this.CTable, this.BTable.nextSibling);
```

```js
document.querySelector("input[type=button]").addEventListener(
  "click",
  function() {
    this.BTable.parentNode.insertBefore(this.CTable, this.BTable.nextSibling);
  }.bind(this),
  false
);
```

```css
.fHTML5,
.fHTML5 td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Click To Move">
<table class="fHTML5">

  <!-- TABLE HEADER-->
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=15>Mass Table -</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="RowHead">
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>P Load (N)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="CTable">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>700 - in CTable</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>800 - in CTable</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="fHTML5">
  <!-- TABLE HEADER-->
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=15>Mass Table -</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="RowHead">
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>P Load (N)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="BTable">
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>In BTable</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>In BTable</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.. Thanks